# How to Parse Facebook Data

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-listview

I am having a few problems getting Facebook data to parse properly.

I am working on implementing part of an application to allow a user to select and use one of their own facebook photos within the app. I have gotten the facebook login/logout code working and I am currently getting the token (once logged in) in order to gather the users Album information. The permission set is also working nicely, however I am now stuck at trying to get the JSON information to parse correctly. Here is a sample snippet of the information I need to parse:

```
 "data": [
  {
     "id": "3486732467234",
     "from": {
        "name": "Persons Name",
        "id": "Persons ID"
     },
     "name": "Vacation",
     "location": "City",
     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=434235&id=324343&aid=2430",
     "cover_photo": "3489234432",
     "privacy": "everyone",
     "count": 60,
     "type": "normal",
     "created_time": "2007-06-03T23:01:16+0000",
     "updated_time": "2011-03-18T19:46:43+0000",
     "can_upload": true
  },
  {
     "id": "4043544665",
     "from": {
        "name": "Persons Name",
        "id": "Persons ID"
     },
     "name": "Vacation 2",
     "location": "City",
     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=4043434665&id=508154335&aid=2555",
     "cover_photo": "5434543",
     "privacy": "everyone",
     "count": 60,
     "type": "normal",
     "created_time": "2007-06-03T22:53:03+0000",
     "updated_time": "2011-03-18T19:45:55+0000",
     "can_upload": true
  }],
...more paging JSON information ...}}
```

I need to be able to pull the album information in order to display the photo album names in a list (and use the ID in another query). Once I can get the albums to show, I would then use those IDs to perform another query to get the photos from that album. Again I can also get that information back, I am just not sure how to properly parse it.

Any useful tips that someone might have in being able to parse this into a listview would be greatly appreciated.

I need to target pulling the first ID and the Album name ("id": "3486732467234" and "name": "Vacation" from the first listing)

Answer (score 5):

why don't you try with the json classes...

something like this:

```
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(your_data);
        jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for(int i =0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            String name= jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            String location= jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("location");
```

etc.

Comment: Thats how I originally tried to do it, however it seems to freak out at the fact that its wrapped within "data" - I think thats where I need to find the root of the issue. If I can get JSON to search within the data array - it should in theory be very simple to get the results.

Comment: heh ... correction I just noticed the whole change to adding data... I will give this a try and see if it will work out. It just looked strikingly similar to the code I was already trying.

Comment: If you want to get the JSON Object right from the response and pass it to your activity: JSONObject userJSON = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

Answer (score 4):

The new Android Facebook SDK 3.0 returns a Response object in the Response.Callback() listener when making Graph API calls.  This response object can be used to create a GraphObject which can be used to get a JSON...ex:

```
Request graphRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, graphRequestString, new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            //Create the GraphObject from the response
            GraphObject responseGraphObject = response.getGraphObject();

           //Create the JSON object
           JSONObject json = responseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

        }
});
```